# Passing a Tuple in merge sort

Tags: scala

Here is merge sort :

```
def msort[T](less: (T, T) => Boolean)
            (xs: List[T]): List[T] = {
  def merge(xs: List[T], ys: List[T], acc: List[T]): List[T] =
    (xs, ys) match {
      case (Nil, _) => ys.reverse ::: acc
      case (_, Nil) => xs.reverse ::: acc
      case (x :: xs1, y :: ys1) =>
        if (less(x, y)) merge(xs1, ys, x :: acc)
        else merge(xs, ys1, y :: acc)
    }
  val n = xs.length / 2
  if (n == 0) xs
  else {
    val (ys, zs) = xs splitAt n
    merge(msort(less)(ys), msort(less)(zs), Nil).reverse
  }
}                                                 //> msort: [T](less: (T, T) => Boolean)(xs: List[T])List[T]
```

I'm trying to define the comparison type of Tuple using :

```
val integerSorter = msort[((String, String), Double)]((a._2, b._2) => a._2 < b._2) _
```

But I receive error :

```
<console>:1: error: not a legal formal parameter
       val integerSorter = msort[((String, String), Double)]((a._2, b._2) => a._2 < b._2) _
```

How can I define integerSorter so that it accepts a Tuple of type `((String, String), Double)` ?

Comment: Shouldn't your function definition be `(a, b) => a._2 < b._2`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your definition to:

```
val integerSorter = msort[((String, String), Double)]((a, b) => a._2 < b._2) _
```